# Finding the segue that was called in a ViewController

Tags: ios6, uistoryboard, segue

I'm using storyboarding and have a UITableView containing events, which when clicked load another view with more details. I also have an 'add' button on that list which goes to the same page but doesn't prepopulate the information and changes the banner button.

I do it by setting the detail item with the following method, and then in the configureView method I just check if the detail item exists.

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem {
    if (self.detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;
        [self configureView];
    } }
```

This works ok, but I thought there might be a better way to distinguish between methods, eg by getting the segue identifier in this new view controller and using that. Is there an easy way to do this or do I need to pass this information through as part of the prepareForSegue method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `prepareForSegue:` seems right.  In general, it's a bad idea for methods to care about the conditions under which they're being called if it's not explicit in their parameters.